# Auto-Suggest JavaScript with Radio Button

Tags: php, javascript

I have one JavaScript through which I am getting a list of companies from memcache with auto-suggest.  If I type 're' in the text box, then it will return all the company names that start with 're'.

I have another JavaScript through which I am getting a list of mutual-fund companies from memcache with auto-suggest as well.  If I type 're' in the text box, then it will return all the mutual-fund company names that start with 're'.

I would like both to work on the same text box with a radio button that lets the user choose between 'ALL', 'MUTUAL FUND', and 'COMPANY', so if 'ALL' is selected, auto-suggest should suggest from both company names and mutual-fund company names based on the text inputted.

I've written my page in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial:

http://www.dynamicajax.com/fr/AJAX_Suggest_Tutorial-.html

And then pass the id for the radio buttons

Comment: I unserstood this code thanks....but now i have added two radion button below List and No List.....I want only if click on List it shud display the list and if i click on No list then no list display....

Comment: Provide sample code of what you got so I understand better please.

Comment: I understood that how to work with autosugest and all.
Now i have one php file 
http://localhost/autosuggest.php?type=mf&search=reliance
as you can see it is returning all the mutual fund company name
I want those in autosuggest if click on radio button 'MF'

and If i click on 'Company' radio button then type='' and shoud show 
all company name only in drop down suggest